# Como abrir uma lista de imagens com OpenCV?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

Estou tentando abrir imagens e mostrar elas em tela de um diretório chamado 'Photos' com várias imagens .jpg, porém quando a janelas abrem elas simplesmente não carregam as imagens e o interpretador não retorna nenhum erro, ele apenas para de funcionar.

```
import cv2 as cv
from os import listdir, path
import time

path = path.dirname(path.realpath(__file__)) + "\Photos"  #Traz o caminho do diretorio atual
files = [f for f in listdir(path)]  #Armazena o nome dos arquivos numa lista
print(files) #['cat.jpg', 'cats 2.jpg', 'cats.jpg']

for file in files:
  img = cv.imread(f'Photos/{file}')
  cv.imshow(f"{file}", img)
  time.sleep(10)
  cv.destroyAllWindows()

cv.waitKey(0)
```

*Nenhuma dessas imagens ocupa muito espaço (a maior só tem apenas 312kbs)

Tela que deveria mostrar a foto:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYy0P.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema está na função `time.sleep`. Essa função interrompe a execução da *main thread*, fazendo o programa "dormir". Consequentemente, o carregamento da imagem na tela também é interrompido, **temporariamente**. Você não consegue ver a imagem sendo carregada na tela — no final do processo — porque após o término da função `sleep`, o programa já fecha a janela, antes mesmo da imagem ser carregada.

Você pode fazer um teste para comprovar isso, removendo a linha de código em que a tela é destruída. Nesse caso, o programa criaria todas as janelas, e as imagens só apareceriam depois de ter acabado todas as execuções da função `sleep` — em outras palavras, após ter acabado o laço de repetição.

```
cv.imshow(f"{file}", img)          # <- Cria a janela e inicia o carregamento da imagem
time.sleep(10)                     # <- Interrompe o carregamento da imagem
cv.destroyAllWindows()             # <- Destrói a tela antes da imagem ser carregada
```

A solução para esse problema é substituir a função `sleep` pela função `cv.waitKey` — pois ela não interrompe a *main thread* — passando como argumento o tempo em milissegundos. Veja abaixo:

```
import cv2 as cv
from os import listdir, path
import time

path = path.dirname(path.realpath(__file__)) + "\Photos"
files = [f for f in listdir(path)]
print(files)

for file in files:
    img = cv.imread(f'Photos/{file}')
    cv.imshow(f"{file}", img)
    cv.waitKey(10000)          # 10 segundos = 10000 milissegundos.
    cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

1. item

```
import cv2
from os import listdir, path
imagem = cv2.imread("lampada.png")
cv2.imshow("Original", imagem)

print "Altura (height): %d pixels" % (imagem.shape[0])
print "Largura (width): %d pixels" % (imagem.shape[1])
print "Canais (channels): %d"      % (imagem.shape[2])
    
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

ou

2. item

```
########################
# Open a file
path = "/var/www/html/"
dirs = os.listdir( path )

# This would print all the files and directories
for file in dirs:
   print file
```